# Desktop "eject" or "quit" does not unmount usb media

Tags: usb, umount

I use a USB device with SD-card slots. It works fine, but I cannot seem to unmount it on a proper way from user space.

1. Right clicking on the memory stick icon and selecting "eject" does nothing
2. Same with "quit" removes the dot and closes the nautilus window, but the SD-card is still mounted accord to "sudo mount | grep /dev/sdc1"
3. umount from user space gives error message (as I suppose it should) "Error unmounting block device 8:33: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Error.Failed: Error unmounting /dev/sdc1: not mounted"
4. sudo umount /dev/sdc1 works fine

This used to work "before", I don't know exactly when.

I am running Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: "umount from user space gives error message" ⇠ what is this error? Could you [edit] your question to include the exact message?